# How to get information about user before he made allow to the application?

Tags: facebook

I ran into this page and I didnt understand how I saw Welcome  and when you click on the name, it goes to your profile page.. meaning the page has your ID and your name before you made an allow for the application.

This is the page I was talking about: https://www.facebook.com/greatdealslka?sk=app_4949752878

Can someone help me to understand how it's done? getting information about the user before allow?

Answer (score 0):

That page is probably using FBML, which is now deprecated.

FBML had some tags that allowed you to do that but such a functionality is not available anymore.